# What does & actually do?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand Rust's reference.

```
fn main() {
    let x: i32 = 0;
    println!("{}", x+1); // this works
    println!("{}", (&x)+1); // this works
    //println!("{}", (&(&x))+1); // but this failed
}
```

What I get:

```
    1
    1
```

What does `&` actually do? Why can `&x` be added like it is an integer but not `&(&x)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` takes the reference of the operand. This can be thought of as finding the memory address that the value is stored at.

Your example works because `+` is implemented using the [`Add` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html), which has the following variants:

```rust
impl Add<i32> for i32
impl<'a> Add<i32> for &'a i32
impl<'a> Add<&'a i32> for i32
impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'a i32> for &'b i32
```

That is, you can add any pair of references and non-references. However, your second example would have two levels of indirection (`&&i32`), and the `Add` trait isn't implemented for that many levels of reference.

Comment: Thanks! Why doest rust implement add trait for reference then?

Comment: @siyu it does - that's the snippet of code I pasted. However, it doesn't implement the trait for a double-reference and a value, which is what your case is.

Comment: Yes. But why do it when it makes things so confusing? (I can't know whether something is an integer or a reference to an integer in a glance)

Comment: Typo in first comment: doest -> does

Comment: siyu@ doubly inderected references are actually quite rare in real-world code. You can dereference manually with `*x`.